# Запуск питон скрипта с двумя десятками вариаций конфига

Tags: python, windows, консоль

Умные програмеры написали на питоне консольную прожку, которая просто божественна. В качестве параметра она принимает конфиг файл. Но вот проблема таких конфигов у меня два десятка, каждый из них открывает отдельный порт. Получается мне нужно столько раз запустить консольку, сколько у меня конфигов. Получается очень неудобная вещь. Может существует какое-то решение, я сам не представляю какое, но вдруг. Платформа венда.

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое - написать `bat` файл, который будет запускать приложение нужное количество раз с различными конфигами.

```
start cmd /C program.py config1.cfg
start cmd /C program.py config3.cfg
start cmd /C program.py config2.cfg
```

И так нужное количество строк. Флаг `/C` означает, что после выполнения программы окно закроется автоматически.

Если не хочется писать большое количество однотипных строк, то можно сделать цикл, который будет пробегать по конфигам в определенной папке и для каждого запускать экземпляр программы. Этим решим еще проблему добавления или удаления  конфига. Как написать цикл - предлагаю разобраться самостоятельно или создать отдельный вопрос

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но проблема в том что через виндовую консоль cmd не получается запустить скрипт. Это можно сделать только через консоль Anaconda. Я пробовал разные вариации, прописывал в PATH путь к питону, но ничего не получается. Можно ли написать bat файл для Anaconda?

Comment: Не пользователя Anaconda... Попробуйте вместе `cmd` в батнике прописать полный путь к исполняемому файлу Anaconda

Comment: @AlexSokolov: "не могу запустить Питон-скрипт в cmd" лучше как отдельный вопрос задать.

Comment: я пробовал самые разные вариации, но без анаконда скрипт не работает :(